# How to update datawindow itemstatus for all the rows in the datawindow without using loops

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I have a datastore, in certain condition i need all of the rows in that to be inserted into database, So i just made a loop and set each item staus to newmodified! and fired update, its working but time consuming, Is there any other ways to handle this without looping, Pelase suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Rowscopy method to copy all the rows into a separate datastore.  This gives them all a 'NewModified! status which will generate inserts.  Something like this

```
li = ds_1.Rowscopy(1, ds_1.Rowcount(), Primary!, ds_2, 1, Primary!)
```

`IF li > 0 THEN
   ds_2.update()...`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the update() method, so all updates will be done to database.

Source: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.help.ase.15.7/title.htm